# Selecting multiple rows at once when I know what ID's I want

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns...ID and Content.

Is there a way to select data from multiple rows at once from a mysql database when I know what row ID's I want to retrieve data from.

Possibly putting the Content column results into an array or some sort if that is the best way.  I am trying to prevent a ton of sql query's.  There are just 2 columns, an ID and a content column.

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `IN` statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: @KDJ, do you mean `SELECT Content from mytable WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)` ?